# Nominativus cum infinitivo

Tags: translation-check, infinitive, nominativus-cum-infinitivo

Can somebody please tell me if my translation for the sentence: "It seems that the slave is carrying a letter." is correct?

> Videtur servus epistulam portare.

videtur - 3rd person present passive

servus - nominative

epistulam - accusative

portare -present infinitive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; when the nominative *servus* **can** be construed as the subject of *videtur,* (or *dicitur, cognoscitur* )

The slave seems to be carrying a letter.
The slave is seen to be carrying the letter.

then
'It seems that the slave is carrying the letter.' is Nominative and infinitive.